# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'client'

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I have a code where, I am establishing connection with MongoDB. This code is

ConnectMongoDB.py:

```py
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
from flask import Flask, render_template, request,redirect,url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

# Connection to MongoDB

class ConnectMdb:
    @staticmethod
    def connect2mongodb():
        global client
        try:
            client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb") # modified to avoid showing actual string. Kindly ignore this part.
            print("Connected to Avengers MongoClient Successfully!!!")
            print (type(client))
            print(client)
        except:
            print("Connection to MongoClient Failed!!!")

        #db = client.avengers_hack_db
        return("Connection established")

if __name__ == '__main__':
   ConnectMdb.connect2mongodb()
```

I import this script in another program which has some business logic. Here is some part of the code which is relevant to this issue:

ProcessData.py:

```py
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
import datetime
import sys
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
#import ProcessTaskData
#import werkzeug
import ConnectMongoDB as cDB
app = Flask(__name__)

CMdb = cDB.ConnectMdb.connect2mongodb()

db = CMdb.client.avengers_hack_db

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/Avengers',methods = ['POST'])  
def Avengers():
    ip = request.remote_addr
    Project_ID = request.form['pid'] 
    Name = request.form['pname'] 
    Resource_Names = request.form['rsrc']

    db.ppm_master_db_collection.insert_many([
            {"Org_Id":"",
             "Name": Name,     
             "last_modified": datetime.datetime.utcnow()}
        ]) 
    return render_template('ptasks.html', user_ip=ip)   

@app.route('/ProjectTasks',methods = ['POST'])  
def ProjectTask():
    ip = request.remote_addr
    Task_ID = request.form['tid'] 
    TAlert = request.form['talrt']
    TResource_Names = request.form['trsrc']

    db.ppm_tasks_data_collection.insert_many([
            {"Task_ID": Task_ID,
             "Resource_Names": TResource_Names,
             "last_modified": datetime.datetime.utcnow()}
            ])  
    return render_template('ptasks.html', user_ip=ip)

if __name__ == '__main__':  
   app.run(debug = True)
```

If I put the code from ConnectMongoDB.py directly in the ProcessData.py rather than importing, it works good. But from separate file it errors.

Also, client is of type:

```
 <class 'pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient'>
```

Ideally it is expected to behave normally (establish connection to db as well) like when the code is in the ProcessData.py. Not sure where am I missing.

Comment: This code has obvious syntax and indentation errors.  We can't help if you don't post your actual code.

Comment: @JohnGordon I have updated the code with full code. Hope that helps?

Comment: if you are getting import error is because of the path, try this before import ConnectMongoDB as cDB:
sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\...CompleteFolderPath where is ConnectMongoDB')
 import ConnectMongoDB as cDB

Comment: @Manuel - I am not sure why am I getting the error. I don't think it is path issue. It has something to do with datatype conversion after importing the package.

Comment: The error message `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'client'` says that you are trying to invoke the `.client` method on the `str` (string) data type. So it is enough to find the `.client` method in the code and find out (press a keyboard shortcut "CTRL" + "F" and find out the text), therefore, the left part is of the string type and why it is not the required object (for example: function, class, module, etc.).

Comment: @s3n0 it is already known which part of the code is causing the issue. But what's the solution?

Comment: Sorry, but you have to find out for yourself by diagnosing (debugging or testing in the Python console). I don't see all your source code or your whole project. You need to find out why `CMdb` is associated as the `str` object and not the another needed object - at the line: `CMdb = cDB.ConnectMdb.connect2mongodb()`. For example, you can try it in the Python console... as first import a neccesary modules... then type command to assign `CMdb` and try typing `type(CMdb)` to verify the `CMdb` object. Is it even a string ? I don't know what you need. So, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing 
`db = CMdb.client.avengers_hack_db`
to 
`db = cDB.client.avengers_hack_db` 
should make your error go away, you are referencing the wrong thing. The return value of your staticmethod is a string, and it has no client attribute.

---

A bit better approach would be if your `connect2mongodb` method would `return client`:

```
class ConnectMdb:
    @staticmethod
    def connect2mongodb():
        try:
            client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb") # modified to avoid showing actual string. Kindly ignore this part.
            print("Connected to Avengers MongoClient Successfully!!!")
            print (type(client))
            print(client)
        except:
            raise Exception("Connection to MongoClient Failed!!!")

        return client
```

This way `db = CMdb.client.avengers_hack_db` would work.

Comment: @Trapil - Thanks a lot a friend. I've used the better approach and it fixes the issue. Looks like I have to implement both the solutions. Because, if I don't change  'db = CMdb.client.avengers_hack_db' to  'db = cDB.client.avengers_hack_db', then I get similar error for db.

'str' object has no attribute 'db'